# Reactjs have <div> wrapper the elements on every 4th elements

Tags: reactjs

React group 4 items in a div with class row. At the moment you can see below I have a `<div>` group around the articles.

```
// articles is array of article object
<div className="row">
    <section className="section--6-or-4-items section-featured campaign-teasers">
        {articles.map(item => <Teaser {...item} key={item.id} />)}
    </section>
</div>
```

Should I create a new component which have `<div>` wrapper around and only accept 4 arrays at a time to render out the articles.

Comment: The second argument in `map`'s callback is index. `index % 4 === 0`

Comment: Am I to understand that you want to wrap a `section` around every set of 4 items from an array? Or you want to limit the display to *only* 4 items?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller around every set of 4 items yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet here is to build your array of articles into an array of 4-length arrays. You can do this using lodash's handy [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs#chunk) method.

Once you've chunked your articles, you can iterate over them in your JSX, something like this:

```
const sections = chunk(articles, 4);

return (
  <div className="row">
    {sections.map((articles, i) => (
      <section className="..." key={i}>
        {articles.map(item => <Teaser {...item} key={item.id} />)}
      </section>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

**Edit**: If you don't want to use lodash, you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to great effect:

```
function chunk(array, size) {
  return array.reduce((chunks, item, i) => {
    if (i % size === 0) {
      chunks.push([item]);
    } else {  
      chunks[chunks.length - 1].push(item);
    }
    return chunks;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim That's nice

Comment: If you're not already using lodash, you can accomplish the same thing fairly easily with `reduce`.

Comment: you happy to supply the reduce resolution? would be great to see

Comment: Edited to add - didn't test but *should* be alright.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I extract rendering to dedicated methods.

```html
<div className="row">
  <section className="section--6-or-4-items section-featured campaign-teasers">
    { this.renderArticles() }
  </section>
</div>
```

Renderer method here...

```js
renderArticles() {
    return createChunks(articles, 4).map((chunk, idx) => (
      <div key={idx}>
        { chunk.map((props, idx) => <Teaser key={idx} {...props} />) }
      </div>
    ));
  },
```

And finally, function which chunks array into smaller array on N size

```js
const createChunks = (array, size) => {
  const copy = array.concat();
  const chunks = [];

  while (copy.length) {
    chunks.push( copy.splice(0, size) );
  }

  return chunks;
}
```

Comment: Agree with you. My answer does not include external dependency, though